# Why can't hyperlinkfield get the data?(asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, asp.net-4.5

developing in : asp.net web forms (4.5)

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="student" />
        <%--<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="idNum" HeaderText="idNum" DataNavigateUrlFields="idNum"  />--%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="idNum" HeaderText="idNum" />
    </Columns>
```

When I use boundfield, I am able to use the data by databinding.

```
    protected void soGrid2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Action act = new Action())
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                string idNum= e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

like above. But if I use HyperLinkField like the commented code, the data appears fine but I cannot get the data from rowDataBound. Someone know why this is? And how to make it a hyperlinkfield?

Comment: The `.Text` property would only get text directly in the cell. If you want to get it from a HyperLinkField, you'll need to access the control within the cell.

Comment: What this `Action` class? Why you initialize it for every row in the grid(even the header and footer)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh I actually have another method from action class.I didn't write here because it was not the point of the question.

Comment: @mason Wow that totally makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remember correctly a `HyperlinkField` places a [`HyperLink` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx) in that cell:

```
protected void soGrid2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var idNumLink = (HyperLink) e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        string idNum= idNumLink.Text;
    }
}
```

Note that i've used `e.Row.Cells[2]` because you have used it. But in your sample it is the second column so you had to use `e.Row.Cells[1]`.

Comment: Will try. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I used e.Row.Cells[2] becuase in Cells[0] there are auto created edit and delete buttons. Any way, it works!! Thankss!!!!